# Starting geddy on heroku fails with Error R11 (Bad bind). What is wrong with the deployment? What am I missing?

Tags: node.js, heroku, geddy

I'm trying out a new deployment into heroku, can't seem to get geddy to run without issues.

I keep getting this error

Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 5768, should be 41113 (see environment variable PORT)

Procfile

```
web: geddy -p 5768
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "oskalisti",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "geddy": "0.3.20",
    "jake": "0.2.31"
  }
}
```

Full Log:

```
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri, 13 Apr 2012 17:47:26 GMT] INFO Server starting with config: {
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "environment": "development",
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "workers": 1,
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "port": "5768",
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "debug": true,
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "rotateWorkers": false,
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "rotationWindow": 7200000,
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "rotationTimeout": 300000,
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "logDir": "/app/log",
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "gracefulShutdownTimeout": 30000,
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "heartbeatInterval": 5000,
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "heartbeatWindow": 20000,
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "staticFilePath": "/app/public",
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     "store": "memory",
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     "key": "sid",
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "sessions": {
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     "expiry": 1209600
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "cookieSessionKey": "sdata",
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "metrics": null,
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   },
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "i18n": {
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     "defaultLocale": "en-us",
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     "loadPaths": [
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:       "/app/config/locales"
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     ]
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   },
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "ssl": null,
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "model": {
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     "useTimestamps": false,
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:     "forceCamel": true
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   },
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "detailedErrors": true,
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   "hostname": null
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri, 13 Apr 2012 17:47:26 GMT] INFO Creating 1 worker process.
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri, 13 Apr 2012 17:47:26 GMT] INFO Server worker running in development on port 5768 with a PID of: 6
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri, 13 Apr 2012 17:47:26 GMT] DEBUG LOGGING STARTED ============================================
2012-04-13T17:47:26+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri, 13 Apr 2012 17:47:26 GMT] DEBUG ============================================================
2012-04-13T17:47:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 5768, should be 22421 (see environment variable PORT)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, found the issue, stupid me.

On the Procfile I shouldn't have used the port number, heroku will provide that port for me with the $PORT variable.

So I made the Procfile look like this:

```
web: geddy -p $PORT
```

And that worked. I also modified the production.js environment configuration file to use the heroku port as well, like so:

```
var config = {
  detailedErrors: false
, hostname: null
, port: process.env.PORT
, sessions: {
    store: 'memory'
  , key: 'sid'
  , expiry: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Notice the **port: process.env.PORT** line there.

Then, if you change your file that way, instead of using the $PORT variable on the Procfile file, you can just start geddy like this:

```
web: geddy -e production
```

Just better practice, that way your production configuration gets loaded, and you can truly support different environments.